# Sweet alert not working properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert2

I am using sweetalert to show a message when an ajax response is success but it doesnot displays properly ie,no sucess icon is shown.

> This is my ajax code

```
var formData = $("#enqform").serialize();
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>tour-package/send-mail',
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 1){
                swal({
                      title: "Thankyou!",
                      text: "Our excecutives will contact you soon.",
                      icon: "success",
                    });
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url() ?>tour-packages';
                }, 100000);
            }
            else{
                swal("Error occured !");
            }
          }
      }); 
      return false;
      e.preventDefault();
  }
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.19.2/sweetalert2.min.css

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.19.2/sweetalert2.min.js

i am using these css and js to access sweetalert.

Comment: You have `icon: "success"`, but I don't see an `icon` property anywhere in SweetAlert's documentation. Perhaps you mean `type: "success"`?

Comment: Sorry i am using this first time can you please tell it properly.

Comment: Change `icon: "success",` to `type: "success",`

Comment: since you're using sweetalert 2 try to use `Swal.fire({})` instead of `swal({})`

Answer (score 18):

changing icon to type worked for me

```js
swal({
  title: "Thankyou!",
  text: "Our excecutives will contact you soon.",
  type: "success",
});
```

Comment: It also worked for me. Can anyone explain why it behaved strangely?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
var formData = $("#enqform").serialize();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo base_url('tour-package/send-mail') ?>',
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json'

          ).done(function(data)
          {
            if(data.status == 1){
                swal({
                      title: "Thankyou!",
                      text: "Our excecutives will contact you soon.",
                      icon: "success",
                    });
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url('tour-packages')?>';
                }, 100000);
            }
            else{
                swal("Error occured !");
            }
          });
       });
```

Comment: In this case he needed to change 'icon' to 'type' parameter.

Comment: why does the documentation for swal2 show only "icon" which does not work?